# Read Shapefiles in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, gis, azure-data-factory, shapefile

I want to find out if it's possible to read shapefiles in Azure Data Factory?

An example will be to store the file into a container, and then manipulate the data of the shapefile with a data flow.

Please let me know.

Thank you.

I've tried loading the file into a container, and reading the file as an Azure Blob, but it doesn't seem to be the correct way of reading a shapefile in this platform.

I'm not sure if there is a support for shapefiles in ADF...

Comment: As per [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs) there is no support for the above kind of files.

Answer (score 0):

ADF does not have native support for reading shapefiles. As called out in the document shared by Rakesh, below are the file formats supported in ADF.

[image]

**Workadound**:
As a workaround you can write your own custom code to read shapefiles and convert them to a format that is supported by ADF. For execution of the custom code in ADF, you can use [custom activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-custom-activity) in Azure Data Factory and then use Mapping data flow activity to transform the data as per the requirement.